# Determinant of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $B$ be a fixed $n\times n$ matrix. 
Find the determinant of the following matrix:

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
B-B_{11}I&-B_{21}I&\cdots&-B_{n1}I\\
-B_{12}I&B-B_{22}I&\cdots&-B_{n2}I\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
-B_{1n}I&-B_{2n}I&\cdots&B-B_{nn}I
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

I obtained the matrix because I wanted to calculate the determinant of the linear operator $T_B(A) = BA - AB$ directly from the matrix. I know that the determinant must be equal to $0$. Are there any methods to calculate this determinant without using arguments like singularity?

Comment: Why **wouldn't** you use arguments like singularity?

Comment: Note: in terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), this matrix is $I \otimes B - B^T \otimes I$

Comment: To expand on Omnomnomnom's comment, the given matrix is same as $-B^{T} \oplus B$, whose eigenvalues are $(\lambda_{i} - \lambda_{j})$, $i,j=1,...,n$, where $\{\lambda_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$. Hence the determinant is zero.